# SOAP Request fails using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I want to consume a simple SOAP request from this Webservice:

http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to
>   process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   WebserviceX.Service.Adapter.IPAdapter.CheckIP(String IP)    at
>   WebserviceX.Service.GeoIPService.GetGeoIP(String IPAddress)

This is the *Exception* I get from the Webservice and this is my code:

```
    $wsdl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL';
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl);

    $functions = $soap->__getFunctions();
    $types = $soap->__getTypes();

    $parameters = array("IPAddress"=> "exampleIPAddress");
    $response = $soap->GetGeoIP($parameters);
```

with a real ip-address instead of "exampleIPAddress", of course.

Thanks

Comment: where do u check this code on local server or remote server. If local server what operating system are you using?

Comment: this code runs on my local vm on Ubuntu. I thought the advantage of soap was, that it doesnt depend on the os?  The other function on this Webservice doenst need any parameters, which works perfectly!

Comment: yes but I wanted to confirm that SOAP extension is enabled that was the reason I asked for OS, u can navigate to php.ini file and check

Comment: i just checked it by calling: extension_loaded('soap). it gave me true

Comment: That error sounds like it is coming from the remote (soap) server, not from your php server.  Try it as is (with "exampleIPAddress") does it fail the same or do you get a response that includes "Invalid IP address"?

Comment: The homepage provides an WEB UI to type in data. there you get response.. Also i checked another Webservice. There i get data, even with parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an error on the soap-server side (thanks James). I tried another IP-Address and its working great. Maybe some ip-areas are not supported :D